# AngularJS enable directive once $http get finishes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
app.controller("MainController", function($scope, $http){
    $scope.items= [];
    console.log('hi');
    $http.get('../assets/data/data.json').then(function(response) {
        $scope.drinks =response.data.drinks;
    });
});

app.directive('cycle', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           $(element).cycle({
               fx: 'fade',
               timeout: 10
           });
        }
    };
});
```

I have the above AngularJS and when I run my page the Console.Log shows `[cycle] terminating; too few slides: 0` and then it shows the `Get Request` after.

How would I be able to run the directive once the `$http.get` has finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try doing this

```
<div cycle ng-if="drinks"></div>
```

that way element that contains directive will be compiled in browser only when the drinks are available

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can use

- [`ng-cloak`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)
- `ng-show` and `ng-hide` and custom `scope` property

Also consider using [animation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24animate) instead of creating manual animation within directive

Comment: The problem is that the directive is running right away. How would this work when there is no data?